Trying out REST API but fails when using PointType, getting Unimplemented gRPC operation
Trying to use ASTRADB Rest API. But getting following error response for Point Datatype
{
  "description": "Unimplemented gRPC operation (Status.Code.UNIMPLEMENTED->501): UNIMPLEMENTED: Unable to encode/decode type ''org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.PointType''",
  "code": 501,
  "grpcStatus": "UNIMPLEMENTED",
  "internalTxId": null
}

Any resolution would be really helpful


Welcome to Stack Exchange! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with DB administration, data modelling, or writing database queries so I voted to have your post moved to Stack Overflow. For future reference, you should post developer questions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Also, you'd get better responses if you updated your question with a sample code that replicates the problem. The more details you can provide, the easier it would be for some to answer. For guidance, see  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Unfortunately, the PointType is not supported by the REST API as the error message states. There are currently no plans to add support for that type since the legacy REST API has been deprecated.
Please consider switching to the new Data API for Astra DB. Cheers!
